# SQL Server : how to refer alias when using CASE within CTE - datatable server-side query

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, datatables

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server to get data from multiple table using `CASE` for a jQuery datatable.

This is my query

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[getAllQuotes]
    @iDisplayLength int,
    @iDisplayStart int,
    @SortCol int,
    @SortDir nvarchar(10),
    @Search nvarchar(255),
    @Status nvarchar(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @FirstRec int, @LastRec int

    Set @FirstRec = @iDisplayStart;
    Set @LastRec = @iDisplayStart + @iDisplayLength;

    WITH CTE_Quotes as
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by case when (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir = 'asc')
                                                then QuoteID
                                        end asc,
                                        case when (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir = 'desc')
                                                then QuoteID
                                        end desc,
                                        case when (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir = 'asc')
                                                then QuoteDateTime
                                        end asc,
                                        case when (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir = 'desc')
                                                then QuoteDateTime
                                        end desc,
                                        case when (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir = 'asc')
                                                then CustomerType
                                         end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir='desc')
            then CustomerType
        end desc,
        case when (@SortCol = 3 and @SortDir='asc')
            then CompanyName
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 3 and @SortDir='desc')
            then CompanyName
        end desc,
        case when (@SortCol = 4 and @SortCol='asc')
            then ContactName
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 4 and @SortCol='desc')
            then ContactName
        end desc,
        case when (@SortCol = 5 and @SortCol='asc')
            then Total
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 5 and @SortCol='desc')
            then Total
        end desc,
        case when (@SortCol = 6 and @SortCol='asc')
            then QuoteBy
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 6 and @SortCol='desc')
            then QuoteBy
        end desc,
        case when (@SortCol = 7 and @SortCol='asc')
            then Status
        end asc,
        case when (@SortCol = 7 and @SortCol='desc')
            then Status
        end desc
    )
    as RowNum,
    COUNT(*) over() AS TotalCount,
    QuoteID, QuoteDateTime, CustomerType = 
    CASE
        WHEN Flag = 'QuoteDB' THEN 'New Customer'
        WHEN Flag = 'LiveDB' THEN 'Existing Customer'
    END , CompanyName =  
    CASE
        WHEN Flag = 'QuoteDB' THEN (SELECT CompanyName FROM dbo.Quote_Companies QCP WHERE QCP.CompanyID = QT.CompanyID)
        WHEN Flag = 'LiveDB' THEN (SELECT CompanyName FROM dbo.Companies CP WHERE CP.CompanyID = QT.CompanyID)
    END,
    ContactName =
    CASE
        WHEN Flag = 'QuoteDB' THEN (SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM dbo.Quote_Contacts QCC WHERE QCC.ContactID = QT.ContactID)
        WHEN Flag = 'LiveDB' THEN (SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM dbo.Contacts CT WHERE CT.ContactID = QT.ContactID) 
    END,
    Total, QuoteBy, Status
    FROM dbo.QUOTE QT
    WHERE (@Search IS NULL
            Or QuoteID LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or QuoteDateTime LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or CustomerType LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or CompanyName LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or ContactName LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or Total LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or QuoteBy LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
            or Status LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
    )
    AND Status = @Status
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_Quotes
WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec AND RowNum < @LastRec
```

end

However I get the following errors when trying to create it

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 94
>   Invalid column name 'CustomerType'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 95
>   Invalid column name 'CompanyName'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 96
>   Invalid column name 'ContactName'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 37
>   Invalid column name 'CustomerType'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 40
>   Invalid column name 'CustomerType'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 43
>   Invalid column name 'CompanyName'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 46
>   Invalid column name 'CompanyName'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 49
>   Invalid column name 'ContactName'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getAllQuotes, Line 52
>   Invalid column name 'ContactName'.

Can anyone please let me know how I go about fixing those errors?

I am not sure how to go about referencing aliases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [cross apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to introduce the CompanyName and other expressions and you'll be able to reference them from the other clauses.

as an aside you do not have to use a row_number() in a cte to page your results if you have sql server 2012 or newer. You can use [offset-fetch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) with your whole case statement in the order by clause.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going through the document and I can somewhat understand the logic behind it but I am not able to put my code into something coherent just yet.

Comment: I was able to get a function going and results coming through but I get an error that I did not get before.Procedure or function 'getAllQuotes' expects parameter '@Search', which was not supplied.

I want that if @Search is blank, it just returns all the records

Comment: never mind, I solved it! Thank you for your guidance